# custom keyboard для telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Я новичок в C# и что бы хоть не много попрактиковаться решил попробовать написать бота для телеграма. Всё бы ничего но у меня не получается создать кнопку для пользователя. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку [edit], расположенную под метками.

Comment: Вы хотите напрямую работать с Telegram Bot API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендовал бы не изобретать велосипед и воспользоваться [готовой библиотекой](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot/blob/master/README.md) для C#. А [тут](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot.examples) есть примеры работы с библиотекой.